# Непонятные отступы при написании миксинов в Pug(jade)

Tags: html, jade, pug

Привет всем! Я написал маленький миксин:

```
mixin item(href, active)
 if(active)
    li(class="active"): a( href=href ): block
 else   
    li: a( href=href ): block
```

Потом вызвал его:

```
+item("#sec1")
```

Что получилось: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="vak-xs-12 vak-md-5 vnav-menu">
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#sec1">rwa</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Ребята, не знаете как убрать этот большой отступ?